# Polymer closing the drawer panel

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

How do I close the drawer panel when I click a paper item. I do not seem to understand the documentation or other similar questions.

```
<paper-drawer-panel responsive-width="800px">
    <paper-header-panel drawer id="drawer">
        <div class="horizontal-section-container">
            <div class="horizontal-section">
                <paper-menu>
                    <paper-icon-item onclick="closeDrawer()" id="icon">
                        <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon></iron-icon>
                        Favorite
                    </paper-icon-item>

                    <paper-item>Inbox</paper-item>
                    <paper-item>Starred</paper-item>
                    <paper-item>Sent mail</paper-item>
                    <paper-item>Drafts</paper-item>
                </paper-menu>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--<ul>
        <li><paper-ripple></paper-ripple>One</li>
        <li><paper-ripple></paper-ripple>Two</li>
        <li><paper-ripple></paper-ripple>Three</li>
    </ul>-->

    </paper-header-panel>
<!-- <paper-header-panel main>
        <paper-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="title">Title</div>
        </paper-toolbar> 
        <div>

        </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
-->
```

I am using polymer with meteor 1.2.1. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `paper-icon-item` (why not use `paper-icon-button` here?) Add the attribute `paper-drawer-toggle`.

So you code will look like:

Favorite

The [docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-drawer-panel) for the `paper-drawer-element` state:

> An element that should toggle the drawer will automatically do so if it's given the paper-drawer-toggle attribute. Also this element will automatically be hidden in wide layout.

Answer (score 1):

this will be an alternative method

```
drawerToggle: function() {
    if (this.$.drawer.narrow && this.$.drawer.getBoundingClientRect().width < parseInt(this.$.drawer.responsiveWidth)) {
        this.$.drawer.togglePanel();
    } else {
        this.$.drawer.forceNarrow = !this.$.drawer.forceNarrow;
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/winedi/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

In the onclick function of your paper element add this snippet.

```
if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
}
```